# Plotting in VS Code-Server (Python)

Tags: python

I setup a Visiual Studio Code-Sever on a Raspbarry Pi. I access the server via Safari from my Ipad. I can run scripts but I can not output plots. It is obvious that plt.show() does not work so I tried jupyter, but the interactive window remains black after I run the cell. There is no error to report but vs code is trying to install jupyter once again, although it is installed in my virtual environment. Similar problems occur when I try to start the output pane of neuron (it is not showing up at all).

Does anyone have ideas or ever had similar errors? It seems that jupyter cannot be accessed correctly.

Best regards!